# Shutdown computer with the remote controller

Tags: 10.04, lirc, xbmc

How can I shutdown the computer with the IR controller ? 
It has many working buttons, which can be used correctly, but the power button doesn't do anything. Is there a way to program a script to a button ? 
Remote controller works with LIRC under XMBC on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 2):

As the root user, you could define something like this in the `~/.lircrc` file (with "POWER" replaced with whatever is correct for your remote):

```
begin
 prog = rawcontrol
 button = POWER
 config = power
end
```

Then add something like this to `/etc/rc.local` or another init script:

```
ircat rawcontrol | (while read line
do
        if [ "x$line" = "xpower" ]; then
                shutdown -h now
        fi
done) &
```

This will have "ircat" watch for events using the "rawcontrol" definitions. When it sees "power" get pressed, it'll shut down the system.